# Bad practice HTML/CSS wrappers

Tags: html, css

For a website I'm currently trying to make I've got multiple pages which have different structures. I currently have all HTML element in a wrapper that is defined like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

The corresponding css I've used for one page is the following

```
    .wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% 45% 45% 5%;
    grid-template-rows: 5% auto 5%;
    width: 100;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

However for another page which also has its content wrapped in the same wrapper, I want to use a different grid layout. To fix this I thought about making a different wrapper class for each website, for example

```
<div class="wrapperhome">
<div class="wrappercontact">
```

and then change the css correspondingly.

I am not very experienced with the use of wrappers and I was wondering whether or not this is bad practice or if there are better ways of dealing with this problem.

Comment: you can create a wrapper class and two layout classes e.g (`.layout`, `.layout-contact`) and add the layout setting in it..

Answer (score 1):

TBH, I don't think it matters that much. But about seeking for the best practice, I feel you.

I'd go with using different classes, `.wrapper` for common properties and if a certain page requires some different ones, `.wrapper-home` and extend (and even, overwrite if necessary) `.wrapper`s properties there.

And then you can use `<div class="wrapper wrapper-home"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub classes

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: 100;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.wrapper.subClassName {
  grid-template-columns: 8% 20% 20% 8%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% auto 5%;
}

.wrapper.anotherSubClassName {
  /*
  Different Layout
  */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'></div>
<div class="wrapper subClassName"></div>
<div class="wrapper anotherSubClassName"></div>
<!-- ANd SO ON -->
```

Comment: The thing I don't like much about this approach is that when you see `<div class="wrapper home"></div>` you don't really understand that `home` class has something to do with `wrapper` later.

Comment: That will not be modified, because that is a main class not a sub class. If you call .wrapper.home for the different grid, it will be modified that grid because of the subclass. That main home class will still remain as it is.